# IIS express site is reachable via telnet but not over browser

Tags: iis-express

I want to make a local iis express site reachable over the internet for testing purposes. Setting up Paypal on the site and I want paypal to be able to reach the dev site running on my pc.

If i telnet to my PC from another computer using the port that the iis express site is running on, it connects ok.

However, when i try to reach the site using a browser, the browser just sits indefinitely.

To eliminate variables, i've tried turning off windows firewall. I've also enabled the DMZ option on the router and pointed it to my PC. I can only pull up the site from a telnet connection. Browser still just sits indefinitely waiting.

Any ideas whats going wrong here? Why can i connect via telnet but not through a browser?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the port that IIS express listens on.  Some ISPs block port 80 to discourage the hosting of web servers.  Make sure to add the port to your URL *http://yourdomain.com:8080/path*.

This could explain why telnet works (port 23 by default) and your web server (port 80 by default) is not working.  I had this same issue with an ISP I was using several years ago.  Changing the port should allow you to workaround this limitation.

Comment: port is not the issue. When i telnet, i telnet to the port that the site is running under, thats how i know i can connect to it. For example, say my ip is 111.222.333.444 and the port is 6789, i would do telnet 111.222.333.444 6789  and i would get connected to the site. But using http://111.222.333.444:6789 in the browser just results in the browser spinning it's wheels waiting for a response.

Comment: one note - it's definitely got something to do with my router. I just connected my PC directly to the cable modem and I'm able to pull the site up in a browser now.  I followed the directions in this article http://johan.driessen.se/posts/Accessing-an-IIS-Express-site-from-a-remote-computer to get the site up. Basically all i changed after removing my router was to add the IP address i got from the cable modem